# Does redis evict keys or subkeys on reaching maximum memory limit?

Tags: caching, redis

On reaching the memory limit does redis evict keys or subkeys ( as in case of maps ) ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, no. You would need to specify an eviction policy in redis.conf file. Heres some useful information on redis eviction: https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: Suppose a eviction policy is specified, will it evict the entire map or just some subkeys in that map ?

Comment: So, redis uses a sampling algorithm for eviction, i.e. it takes a sample of keys from its database and applies the eviction policy on that sample set, rather than doing an exact eviction (for eg. evicting the global least recently used key, for lru eviction). That said, I dont believe that redis associates a timestamp with the individual members of the container data-structure. So, it will evict the whole map.

Comment: As @nsuneja wrote - eviction (and expiry) in Redis are at key level. Fields in hashes, elements in lists and members of sets *are not* evicted (or expired) independently, only entire keys (and their values).